# ClientDataset performance TBlobfields

Tags: performance, delphi, blob, tclientdataset

Opening a TClientDataset, and fetching 10.000 rows wich contain 3 TBlobfields takes **3 minutes**.

Opening *exactly* the same data, but casting the BLOB fields as Varchar, takes **1 second** !

The only difference is ,that the TQuery (or the TsqlQuery) has TStringfields, instead of TBlobfields. but the data is the same. The whole table, saved to file, is about 3 MB.
I get the same results using TsqlQuery, or TQuery for connecting to the (firebird) database.

The database is on a server, running Firebird 2.1. The difference is gone when running the database on the client (both < 1 second), so it must be something with networktraffic I suppose...

It gets even more strange :
It does not matter wheter or not the Clientdataset is actually filled with the BLOB-fields.
So, if the clientdataset has only 1 persistent field (number integer), the performance is the same...

This bug(?) is a big problem for me...I hope somebody can explain this...

Answer (score 3):

Check out this post on the [Firebird FAQ website](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq52/)

In a nutshell it says:

1. If you query tables with BLOBs without actually reading BLOB data (just doing SELECT *) it is a good idea to remove them from the column list, since BLOBs require two trips to the server (one to retrieve BLOB ID and other the retrieve the data). Alternatively, you can cast BLOB to varchar to get some the data faster:

select ..., cast(my_blob_field as varchar(2000))

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. maybe that's the problem, but a performance drop from 1 second to 3 minutes, for that 1 extra trip? Is that likely ?

Comment: I'm sure there's more to it than that.  My first question when I read your post was "why on earth would you want to retrieve 3,000 blobs all at once"?  Since blobs can be various sizes and data, you never really know what you're getting unless you cast..  what exactly are you storing in the blob fields?

Comment: The use is storing Rich Text. It was not designed to retrieve that much data, but some of my clients recently imported some external files with > 10.000 records, and that caused to freeze the program for 4 minutes. I'm just trying to get it to work for them, and since casting does it for me, I hope it also works with the rich text sowhn in the grid....

Answer (score 0):

So the interactions are roughly:

- send the query to the server & prepare it
- ask for data (you get a "block" of your results back).
- as the block becomes exhausted the FB client asks for more data
  so these come back as "as many rows that can fit in a block" type scenario.

When you include a Blob, typically the BlobID is returned in a block and then when you actually ask in your app to access the data, it goes off an does another specific request for that Blob from that row.  This is a synchronous round trip = delay.  10K records = 10K round trips at least.
HIH
JAC